Blogging on Substack vs personal website
I'm not a web developer, but I'm comfortable enough with HTML that I can write a static website, and keep the blog under https://username.com/blog/ – hosting is free, and the domain name is a negligible sunk cost.
I also do not plan to charge for access or write very regularly. What I want is to reach the biggest audience when I do write something.
So I'm wondering about the remaining pros and cons of blogging on Substack vs a personal website.
I know that Substack allows users to subscribe. But with a static site, I can just ask the readers to follow me on X so that they won't miss future posts?
And if they want to discuss my post, let them tweet at me – that helps the post spread, right?.

This seems to have been answered extensively on the web. I could summarize the opinions for you, but I'm too lazy. Maybe you want to do the work of researching the answer for yourself instead of asking us to do it for you?

A static website is a pain if you want to add features like letting people comment. You might consider using a company that offers free blog accounts: WordPress, Wix, Weebly, Drupal, etc.
They have all sorts of plug-in features that would take you forever to script on your own website.
There are quite a few more companies out there, just do a Google search.

I'm going to have to be true to myself and my abilities at development and design, which kinda sound closely in line with yours, and offer my recommendation in one simple word - Blogger.
First, Blogger is free, even to attach to your own private domain. It's also free to host which can help in the budget department because you won't need third-party web hosting.
Even if you're looking to sell stuff you can still do that on a Blogger page if you get a little creative and play around with some templates or make your own.
The whole site easily works off HTML or Java so as far as adding special features go it's pretty simple.
You can create multi pages to make it more friendly in the way of categorizing. Otherwise, tags keep it simple.
You can customize everything from the font to the color to whatever you feel like switching up to make it your own.
Posting is quick and simple, included a friendly mobile app and allows for all the pictures, videos and other content you may want to showcase.
Lastly, I'd argue that with Blogger you've got an easy user-friendly low-code interface and backdoor that makes it easy to incorporate Google analytics, Search Console and other products on top of the simple 'flip a switch' solution to enabling Google AdSense if you're looking to include monetizing your content.
I love it and host my business on Blogger and have for the past 4 years. I've tried Substack and hated it. Tried other web builders and they all had their ups and downs but usually ended with me being frustrated and limited in my developing my creative vision and just about all ended up wanting money somewhere for something.
If not Blogger, I'd recommend Google Sites for every single reason that I listed above. It's the same parameters with Sites - free, easy, custom and easy to integrate.

Please don't roll back well-meaning edits without good reason. This is a collaborative site where editing other people's posts is encouraged, and I believe my edits were an objective improvement over the original answer.

A personal site always gives you more freedom of action. But if you use sites like Substack, it gives you benefits like a better user experience or features like chat or others, which in turn is valuable. Also, sites like Substack or Medium allow you to introduce the readers of other blogs to your blog and thus grow faster. In any case, this is a personal choice.
